# How to find out last read/unread Document in sharepoint Document Library?

Tags: document, library

I need to find out the last read\unread document in a document library, optionally filtering the search process to only include documents (read?/modified?/created?) within a speciefied date range.

Can anyone provide any indication on how I should solve the problem?

Comment: Actual requirement was to find the last read\unread documents with in a date range.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would like a Last Accessed timestamp on your documents? This information is, however, not available in SharePoint. You will need to build a custom solution that leverages the audit log to deduce that information.

Answer (score 0):

The Out of the Box Audit Log might help you here. Check Site Actions - Site Settings - Site Collection Administration - Configure Audit Settings.

Comment: It is not correct way .I need to Custom developing .

Comment: What's wrong with it? What do you need a custom solution to do?

Comment: I believe the Audit Log report (invoked by the settings James mentioned above) will contain the information you are looking for - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx

Comment: His requirement was to find the last read and unread documents from a library. So he needs a custom development.

Comment: In Audit log i have everything  but i need  find Latest unread document .